# Django URLconf: redirect while preserving URL's query part and unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

Normally redirect in URLconf is done like this:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (ur'^old/$', 'redirect_to', {'url': ur'/new/', 'permanent': False}),
)
```

Additionally I need GET query to stay in place (`domain.com/old/?p=0` => `domain.com/new/?p=0`).

I done it this way:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (ur'^old/$', lambda request, url, permanent: redirect_to(request = request, url = url + (request.META['QUERY_STRING'] and ('?'+request.META['QUERY_STRING'])), permanent = permanent), {'url': ur'/new/', 'permanent': False}),
)
```

And it works just fine.

Go forward with named regular-expression groups:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (ur'^old/(?P<id>\d+)/$', lambda request, url, permanent, id: redirect_to(request = request, url = url + (request.META['QUERY_STRING'] and ('?'+request.META['QUERY_STRING'])), permanent = permanent, id = id), {'url': ur'/new/%(id)s/', 'permanent': False}),
)
```

Tested and works well.

The place I stuck: if there are Unicode characters in query values, e.g. `?city=Orléans`,  it runs into:

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    not enough arguments for format string
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/simple.py in redirect_to, line 39
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Orléans' in URL 'percent-encoding' is 'Orl%C3%A9ans': [URI and IRI handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#uri-and-iri-handling)

So `redirect_to` falls trying to parse this '%'s.

The solution is to decode query string to get rid of '%'s, e.g. using `urllib2.unquote`

So the final code would be:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to
from urllib2 import unquote

urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (ur'^old/(?P<id>\d+)/$', lambda request, url, permanent, id: redirect_to(request = request, url = url + (request.META['QUERY_STRING'] and ('?'+unquote(request.META['QUERY_STRING']).decode("utf8"))), permanent = permanent, id = id), {'url': ur'/new/%(id)s/', 'permanent': False}),
)
```

Can anyone make it look better? :)

**Update**

Another solution is mentioned in [django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to):

> Because keyword interpolation is always done (even if no arguments are passed in), any "%" characters in the URL must be written as "%%" so that Python will convert them to a single percent sign on output.

**Update**

Since Django 1.3 there is built-in class-based view [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview), which do all the job without hassle.